# First time CUDA programming

Tags: cuda

First time CUDA coding, no errors of running, but the results are weird.

```
0 0 0 5581936
1 1 1 -1717986920
2 2 2 -854341140
3 3 3 19132063
4 4 4 -858993459
5 5 5 8001888
6 6 6 19124671
7 7 7 -682560762
8 8 8 3349568
9 9 9 3351040
10 10 10 1448006405
11 11 11 2435322
12 12 12 0
13 13 13 2130567168
14 14 14 7088378
15 15 15 0
Press any key to continue . . .

#include<iostream>
#include<cuda.h>

using namespace std;

void value_ints(int *a, int N)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    a[i] = i;
}

__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    c[blockIdx.x]=a[blockIdx.x]+b[blockIdx.x];
}

#define N 16
int main()
{
    int *a, *b, *c;
    int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;
    int size=N*sizeof(int);

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c, size);

    a=(int *)malloc(size); value_ints(a, N);
    b=(int *)malloc(size); value_ints(b, N);
    c=(int *)malloc(size);

    cudaMemcpy(d_a, &a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, &b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    add<<<N,1>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c);

    cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<" "<<*(a+i)<<" "<<*(b+i)<<" "<<*(c+i)<<endl;
    }

    free(a); free(b); free(c);
    cudaFree(d_a); cudaFree(d_b); cudaFree(d_c);

    system("pause");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what results you are expecting?

Comment: I find those results just perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

`a` and `b` should be passed by value, not reference to `cudaMemcpy`.